# Completely remove sidebar from MediaWiki

Tags: css, mediawiki

How do I completely remove the sidebar from MediaWiki, and I mean in the sense that the content div occupies 100% of the width of the browser space? I've successfully implemented an extension where non-registered users do not have a sidebar or toolbox to begin with and hence the extra space now seems rather superfluous in such cases.

I'm trying to create my own skin from Vector and have tried so far to change the `margin-left: 10em` and corresponding tags in `div#content` and `mw-panel` in the skin's css file but no luck so far.

Comment: Im hope you want to remove a particular div content entirely,well you could do that using Jquery using `$('#side-bar').remove()`.

Comment: Better simulate in http://jsfiddle.net ,so that i can better understand your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use CSS then you can try,

```
#sidebar{
   display:none;
}
```

to see if it gives you the desired effect.

Or you can do what  *dreamweiver* said and use JQuery

```
$('#side-bar').remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use CSS when you can edit the sidebar menu and have this stored in the database

Navigate to *MediaWiki:Sidebar* edit the page and remove the components you don't need

Comment: That will not remove unused space, and, at least in the version that I am running, the toolbar just won't go away, no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you are writing, you are creating your own skin, then you simply do not have to print the sidebar! It is there because you have a piece of code in your skin printing it.

Search your skin code for `$this->data['sidebar']`, and you will find the loop that prints the sidebar.

However, I'm guessing that you skin has some kind of navigation,and rather than reinventing the wheel, I would recommend using the sidebar, with it's built-in functionality (possible to set from `MediaWiki:Sidebar`, etc), even if you chose to use it in another fashion. it doesn't have to be printed as a sidebar,just because that's the name -- it could be a top menu, a dropdown, ...